# Format Properly Message from MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted

Tags: solidity, javascript

Hello I'm interacting with a smart contract and I have require function in the solidity smart contract, I would like to show these messages properly formatted in the console when I log the error I get type object but I cannot acces properties can someone shed light, thanks ahead!

```
console.log(e.message)

Error: execution reverted: Already claimed
{
  "originalError": {
    "code": 3,
    "data": "0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f416c726561647920636c61696d65640000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "message": "execution reverted: Already claimed"
  }
}
    at Object._fireError (index.js?5ba3:49)
    at sendTxCallback (index.js?7789:539)
    at cb (util.js?3022:689)
    at callbackifyOnRejected (util.js?3022:666)
    at eval (process.js?4362:5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working on a similar issue, not sure if you have figured this out, but some of the actual error message data comes back as a stringified JSON object. In my experience those errors usually come with `code:` and `message:` keys inside. You would to take say `error.message`, and `JSON.parse()` it.

For me the issue is I need to build an error handler to handle the 3 object formats i've encountered. Ideally I'm going to build it to handle RPC errors plus others. It kind of depends where the tx reverts too. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: I did manage to fix this thank you!
`return common.Hash{}, &rpc.CustomError{Code: -32602, ValidationError: "Your error message"}`

Comment: Yay! Glad to hear!!